# How can I choose a parameter type in callback function when a document says it can be either

Tags: node.js

In [this document](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) it says "chunk" is either a string or Buffer, but in the following example code,

```
var fs = require('fs');
var is = process.stdin;
var os = fs.createWriteStream('./output.txt');

os.on('pipe', function(src){
  console.log('pipe event');
});

is.on('data', function(data){
  console.log('data :', data.constructor);
  if ( data.trim() == 'exit' ) {
    console.log('exit!');
    is.unpipe(os);
  }
});

is.pipe(os);
```

"data" always seems like a Buffer as I log "data"s constructor, so trim() throws an exception that trim is not a function

How can I do something for the 'data' to be the type of 'String'?

Comment: From that page (emphasis mine): *"The listener callback will be passed the chunk of data as a string **if a default encoding has been specified** for the stream using the `readable.setEncoding()` method"*

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh I should've read that more carefully, Thanks!(I just typed the example code without setEncoding part in online teacher's ppt page so I missed that)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Buffer.toString()](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) could help?

RTFM ;)